# How to specify CORS settings when creating Azure Storage account from Azure Management Fluent

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-sdk

I'm using Azure Management Fluent library to create storage account. Something like that:

```
var storageAccount = await azure.StorageAccounts.Define(accountName)
           .WithRegion(azureDefaults.Location)
           .WithExistingResourceGroup(azureDefaults.StorageResourceGroup)
           .WithGeneralPurposeAccountKindV2()
           .WithOnlyHttpsTraffic()
           .WithBlobEncryption()
           .CreateAsync();
```

However I also need to specify CORS settings. How can I do this with Fluent configuration?

I know there is a [way to do this in old-style library](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32898415/809357), but I'd like to avoid using 2 libraries for creating a single storage account.

Comment: Ticket created https://github.com/Azure/azure-libraries-for-net/issues/442

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this myself, but there is a library for **CorsSettings Class**, it's under the **Microsoft.Azure.Management.AppService.Fluent.Models** Namespace. This could be used after you define your storage account, more about it can be found **[here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.appservice.fluent.models.corssettings?view=azure-dotnet)**

Comment: I'm not seeing how to apply this class to the created storage account

Comment: Let me check with the internal team to see how it's possible to use it.

Comment: I've seen that class when I trawled through the source code of *.Fluent libraries. As far as I can see, it is only applicable to WebApps, not for storage.